# how can I keep the language query parameter from a cookie value while switching pages?

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I'm trying to programmatically add a query parameter containing the language information to the page-URLs and preserve it while switching pages.

I'm using Express and I18N (4+) + cookie parser.

I have tried to add:

```
 res.setLocale('de');
 res.setLocale(req, 'de');
 req.setLocale('de');
```

I found above example in the docs, however, this does not allow me to switch languages after.

My current code:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(i18n.init);

i18n.configure({
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  queryParameter: 'lang',
  cookiename: 'lang',
  directory: __dirname + '/locales',
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    res.locals.__ = res.__ = function() {
    return i18n.__.apply(req, arguments);
};

    res.cookie('lang', res.getLocale(), { expires: new Date(Date.now()});
    console.log(res.getLocale() + ' language is set');

    next();

});
```

I can set the page URL to pagename?lang=de but on switching ULRs the locale jumps back to default language..
Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks